# How to Handle Exception with Bulk Data Operations With NHibernate's Stateless Sessions

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have developed below meioned Code for Bulk Data Operations With NHibernate's Stateless Sessions.

```
var testObjects = CreateTestObjects(500000);
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var testObject in testObjects)
            {
                Session.Save(testObject);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Now my question is suppose I have 10 items in my `testObjects` and 5th no Item contains the wrong schema or any other exception then how can I handle this transaction I mean to say 5 Items already commit and after that the exception occure then other 5 item would not be commited  due to transaction failed if so then how can I handle this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure I've understood the question, but the transaction pourpose is exactly doing what you described...

Comment: @FelicePollano I have modofied question

Comment: The foreach is inside the transaction, so you should not find the first items committed if one fails.

Comment: you mean to say it would automatically handle suppose one item fail in loop ?

Comment: yes, in the sense that no one would go in the database

Comment: but I want to handle it I mean if one is fail then cycle will not be stop othres have to store into database is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `foreach` loop is inside the transaction, if one item fails in the middle, no one will reach the database. So there is no need for a special handling.